# Проблема с блоками

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Здравствуйте, раньше это заметно не было, а если сделать текст чуть подлинее, то блоки начинают смещаться как-то не понятно, [вот сайт](http://arendushek.ru/?do=views)

[image]

С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: так работает float. ничего особенного. используйте [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: телепатМод On  

хоть бы немножко кода, а то рыться в каталогах - не торт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Зачем в div вкладывать ul ??
2. Что за минусовые марджины?? Срочно избавьтесь от них
3. вместо float: left в данной ситуации лучше использовать display: inline-block;
4. Если уж очень хочется делать через флоат: лефт, то после каждого поcледнего блока в ряду нужно вставлять div cо стилями clear: both; width: 100%; height: 0

Comment: @mountpoint поставил я inline-block не помогло

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, посмотри как тут сделано. проанализируй через инспектор кода и посмотри на стили блоков product-item.

ВАЖНО!!! Если используешь inline-block, то float: left нужно убрать. вместе они не работают